# JPA composite key spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I made 2 one-to-one relationships with 2 foreign keys, but I can't make a constraint or how could I make the 2 unique keys be a unique key in the new table?

```
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private int quantity;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product products;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User users;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private Double price;
    private String image;
```

It spells my 2 keys correctly, for example
user_id = 2 , product_id =2 would be ok
but if I enter another user_id=2, product_id=2 should not work, but for me it is entered in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html) in the `@OneToOne` relation:

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Product products;
```

Comment: when I do that, it doesn't insert any value, it inserts NULL for foreign keys

Comment: Have you tried without `referencedColumnName`  value?